# fadeIn() not triggering but everything else is

Tags: javascript, html, css, socket.io

I have this small snippet that triggers when I use socket.io:

```
socket.on('wheelspin', function (random) {
    var img = document.querySelector('img');
    $("img").fadeIn();
    console.log('wheelspin!!!');
    console.log('fadeIn');

        img.removeAttribute('style');
        var deg  = 0; 

        console.log('deg = ' + deg);
        console.log('Number = ' + random);
        if(random == 0) {var deg = 15; var css = '-webkit-transform: rotate(' + deg + 'deg);'; }
        img.setAttribute('style', css);
}
```

Whenever I run this, the webpage console displays the console.logs but it doesn't do the fadeIn. If I do the following outside the socket trigger it works:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("img").fadeIn();
 });
```

Any advice?

Thanks

Comment: It's worth removing all ordinary js-query and setAttribute methods because fadeIn uses the style attribute as well to change opacity or you can try to put fadeIn at the end of the callback.

Comment: @Blauharley I need to use set.attribute etc to make it rotate.

Answer (score 0):

Probably `$("img").fadeIn();` is not working because the img is not yet available and socketio's 'wheelspin' event is being emmited before that. this is evident from the fact that  `$("img").fadeIn();` works pretty well inside `$(document).ready()` when the DOM is ready.

**suggestion:** 
Use everything when the DOM is ready

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    socket.on('wheelspin', function (random) {
          var img = document.querySelector('img');
          $("img").fadeIn();
          console.log('wheelspin!!!');
          console.log('fadeIn');

          img.removeAttribute('style');
          var deg  = 0; 

          console.log('deg = ' + deg);
          console.log('Number = ' + random);
          if(random == 0) {var deg = 15; var css = '-webkit-transform: rotate(' + deg + 'deg);'; }
          img.setAttribute('style', css);
     }
 });
```

Comment: So, I've just tried that, it's saying it's missing a ")" but I don't believe it is as DOM doesn't wrap it? http://pastebin.com/M6JVGqeK